# If $\mu $ is mutually singular with $\nu$ and absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$, show that $\mu=0$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Here is a problem I want to confirm my answer to.

> Let $\mu $ and $\nu$ be two non-negative measures on a $\sigma$ - algebra $M$. If $\mu$ is mutually singular with $\nu$ and absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$, show that $\mu=0$

**My proof:** Since $\mu$ is mutually singular with $\nu$, that implies the support of $\mu$ and the support of $\nu$ have an empty intersection. Now, if $\mu$ is not identically $0$, there exists an $A \in M$ such that $\mu(A)>0.$ But then $\nu(A)>0$ as well since, if $\nu(A)=0$, then $\mu(A)=0$. But then $A$ is a set for which both measures are positive, i.e. $A$ is in both the support of $\mu$ and the support of $\nu$. But that's a contradiction since support of $\mu$ and support of $\nu$ have empty intersection.

Thanks!

Comment: looks good for me :)

Comment: thanks! I was just confused because of the way my book defines mutually singular, saying u and v mutually singular if there exists an C and D disjoint measurable sets such that $\mu(A)= \mu(A\cap C)$ and $v(A)=v(A\cap  D)$ for all measurable sets A.$ Then I read another book where they use my support definition. I guess the two are equivalent?

Comment: yes they are equivalent:
if we have that $\mu(A)=\mu(A\cap C)$ for every set $A$ then for every $B \subseteq D$ we have that $\mu(B)=\mu(B\cap C)=\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and vice versa.

Comment: perfect, so basically in this case the support of $\mu$ would be C and that of $v$ would be D right?

Comment: yes, exactly right

Comment: Thanks! by the way would the answer to this change if only $\mu$ were assumed non negative? In that case we would have $\mu(A)>0$ which implies v(A) is not 0 which again implies the intersection of their supports contains A, contradiction?